# In order to store and process credit card data, a payment application built on force.com need a PCI DSS or PA DSS validation?

Tags: community, force.com

**Requirement:**

Build a Payment Application on force.com that store and process Credit Card Number using different gateway API calls.

**Facts:**

Salesforce is a PCI (PCI DSS 3.1) certified  service provider.

**Question:**

The Payment Application should opt for **PCI DSS** or **PA DSS** ?

Hoping for answer from someone with expertise in both Salesforce/ PaaS and PCI.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **PCI DSS**.

Since no one answered this question in last two years, I'm answering my question after finding the solution.

The Payment Processing Application that process payments using webservice callout to a PSP and built on SFDC can be PCI compliant.

Also the customer/buyer of this application needed to be PCI compliant too.
PCI is a shared responsibility between Salesforce, ISV partner and the application customer.